# throw out user after a minute passed?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I want to make a "special" type of guestbook, where only one random guest can write something at a time. When a user goes to the guestbook, it becomes locked for other users - the other users can't write, but they can read all the previous entries.

The user who "claimed" the guestbook has one minute to write his comment. When the time passes or when he posts his comment, he automatically gets locked out of the page and the guestbook becomes available to the next user. When you tried to write to the guestbook, no matter if you managed to post a comment or not, you're unable to write something into the guestbook for half an hour (but you can still view every entry like normal).

How can I accomplish this? I heard I had to use something like cronjobs, but is that really what I need? If somebody could give me some pointers (not expecting whole solutions), that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me summarize this a little..

- You want to make a user able to write something in your guestbook.
- This person only has 1 minute to make this message
- The user then will be redirected somewhere
- Next person can then write something

A solution:

What you could do is set up a database and let every user have a session, using session_start(); You then write that session_id() into the database with the current time. You then let an ajax call check for that time every 20 seconds or so. You then remove this session_id and lock the controls for that user.

If a user tries to post something but another user is busy typing, you can add that users id to a self build queuing system inside the database. You should then calculate the amount of queued users times 1 minute.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: I like that, it sounds like a very simple implementation. But it seems a bit too simple...if I do checks through AJAX, couldn't someone intentionally try to block the guestbook from being unlocked? What if the user just leaves the page?

Comment: Haha, and thats why you compare the time + one minute with the current time when a new user tries to post something. With this, a new person can easily unlock a locked guestbook, and with that, the problem of locking is solved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - this does seem to be what I'm looking for, and the one answer I can actually (possibly) realize. Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest doing this work in Java, assuming you have a central server that the applications are connecting to.

If no, you can manage this in the database.  What you want to do is lock the table.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) is information on locking tables.

It is also important that you unlock the table.

One method is to wait 60 seconds in a thread and then do the unlock.  Another possiblity is to let the database do the work via an [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

I will note that you want to be *very careful* with such an application.  If any component fails or doesn't behave as expected, the lock on the table may not be released.  This is one reason why I suggest doing this work on the server side.  In addition, you seem to have only one element that is being changed; using the mechanisms of a relational database for a single element is often overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a few things in the architecture to make this happen. Ultimately it comes down to the flow of the interaction for your website.

Architecture suggested - Server Side Language (suggest Java), Websockets, Database, and a Scheduled Task (Cron, scheduled task, etc)

1. You have your guest book page.
2. When a user accesses the comment section the website sends a "lock" command to the server which would lockout all other users. (Ideally you would use websockets so communication can be two way)
3. If the LOCK command is sent from the server back to the viewers then you disable the comment box.
4. Along with locking the comment box (readonly/disabled/etc) you need to ensure that the lock is persisted to a user on the server so that anyone using the API couldn't write to the guest book via the api by doing a user lock lookup based on the user submitting the api request.
5. Once a user is writing into their comment box you set a `setTimeout` that after 1 minute it removes the server locks and alerts all other clients that the lock has been lifted (enabling their comment boxes).
6. Have a scheduled task via Java, cron, etc that will ensure no clients have the lock and that the lock is not set in the database.

This is a tricky implementation and will have a lot of gotchas as you could potentially lose communication with the server to release the lock if the lock is still enabled on the server but no client has the lock.